# Outlook formatting different between new email editor and received item

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2016, text-formatting, styles

I've created a style to make it easy to format code snippets in emails. When I apply the style, it looks like this in the new email window:

[image: before]

However, when the email is received, it adds some weird whitespace padding between the border and the shading:

[image: after]

Is there any way to fix this from within Outlook?

**Edit:** Adding the HTML source of the email as requested in the comments:

```
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <head>
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)">
        <style>
            <!--
            /* Font Definitions */
            @font-face
                {font-family:Calibri;
                panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
            @font-face
                {font-family:Consolas;
                panose-1:2 11 6 9 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
            /* Style Definitions */
            p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
                {margin:0in;
                margin-bottom:.0001pt;
                font-size:11.0pt;
                font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;}
            a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
                {mso-style-priority:99;
                color:#0563C1;
                text-decoration:underline;}
            a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
                {mso-style-priority:99;
                color:#954F72;
                text-decoration:underline;}
            p.MsoListParagraph, li.MsoListParagraph, div.MsoListParagraph
                {mso-style-priority:34;
                margin-top:0in;
                margin-right:0in;
                margin-bottom:0in;
                margin-left:.5in;
                margin-bottom:.0001pt;
                font-size:11.0pt;
                font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;}
            p.Code, li.Code, div.Code
                {mso-style-name:Code;
                mso-style-link:"Code Char";
                margin-top:12.0pt;
                margin-right:0in;
                margin-bottom:12.0pt;
                margin-left:.2in;
                background:#EFF0F1;
                border:none;
                padding:0in;
                font-size:10.0pt;
                font-family:Consolas;
                color:#242729;}
            span.CodeChar
                {mso-style-name:"Code Char";
                mso-style-link:Code;
                font-family:Consolas;
                color:#242729;
                background:#EFF0F1;}
            span.EmailStyle20
                {mso-style-type:personal-compose;
                font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
                color:windowtext;}
            .MsoChpDefault
                {mso-style-type:export-only;
                font-size:10.0pt;
                font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;}
            @page WordSection1
                {size:8.5in 11.0in;
                margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;}
            div.WordSection1
                {page:WordSection1;}
            -->
        </style>
    </head>
    <body lang=EN-US link="#0563C1" vlink="#954F72">
        <div class=WordSection1>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Good morning,<o:p/>
            </p>
            <p class=MsoNormal>
                <o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>
            </p>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Test text.<o:p/>
            </p>
            <div style='mso-element:para-border-div;border:solid #AEAAAA 1.0pt;padding:1.0pt 4.0pt 1.0pt 4.0pt;background:#EFF0F1;margin-left:.2in;margin-right:0in'>
                <p class=Code style='margin-left:0in;background:#EFF0F1'>var test = new Test();<o:p/>
                </p>
            </div>
            <p class=MsoNormal>More text.<o:p/>
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will need to supply the html for your style too if you want us to be able to figure it out.

Comment: @LPChip I've edited my comment to include the HTML source for the email.

Answer (score 1):

Your code below uses ' where it should use ". Outlook does understand the ' but its not html complient.

```
        <div style='mso-element:para-border-div;border:solid #AEAAAA 1.0pt;padding:1.0pt 4.0pt 1.0pt 4.0pt;background:#EFF0F1;margin-left:.2in;margin-right:0in'>
            <p class=Code style='margin-left:0in;background:#EFF0F1'>var test = new Test();<o:p/>
            </p>
        </div>
```

Changing this to `<div style=" .... "` and `<p class=Code style=" ... "` should solve it.

Comment: This is interesting because I made the Style in outlook's UI. How can I get to the HTML for the style itself? I just posted the source of the email after I had sent it...